# Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_style_get: assertion `GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed

Tags: qt, ubuntu, build, widget, gtk

After a static build of my qt application

```
./configure -static -debug-and-release  -confirm-license -nomake demos -nomake examples -nomake tools
```

it works fine but I get several output messages yelling:

```
(MyApplication:32030): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_style_get: assertion `GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
```

Is there really a critical problem, should I rebuild qt with different option?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is kind of late, but hopefully it will save someone else some time.

For me, the error was being caused by the combination of two things: `QCleanlooksStyle` and `QTableWidget`. On ubuntu, the default style is either `QCleanlooksStyle` or `QGtkStyle` (which inherits from `QCleanlooksStyle`). When a `QTableWidget` is painted with either one of these styles, I saw that error. My solution was something like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    a.setStyle(new QPlastiqueStyle());

    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It was really problem around Cleanlooks style. For me also sometimes the window of my application expands to incredible dimensions (if there are widgets like QTextWidget etc.). But after switching to 'Fusion' the both problems were disappeared.

Answer (score 3):

In PyQt5 you can use the following code to avoid the problem.

```
app = QApplication()
app.setStyle('Fusion')
```

I think it is a problem of style 'GTK+'.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem with static build of Qt. If you put this code before everything else in main method problem goes away:

```
#ifdef Q_WS_X11
    qputenv("LIBOVERLAY_SCROLLBAR", 0);
#endif
```

Comment: What? Can you elaborate on this answer please? This is not valid code on its own.